# seleccionar de una base de datos todos los elementos repetidos

Tags: base-de-datos, sqlite

Necesito realizar un buscador de articulos que al ingresar las primeras letras me muestre toda la informacion de esos articulos(Por ej si ingreso spr me muestre todos los articulos que empiecen con spr y su respectivo codigo y precio)

Mi_conexion=sqlite3.connect("facturador/facturador2.db")

```
    Mi_cursor=Mi_conexion.cursor()

    Mi_cursor.execute("SELECT NOMBRE_ARTICULO FROM facturador2 ")

    Mi_conexion.commit()

    datos=Mi_cursor.fetchall()

    for i in datos:
        nueva_lista = [s for i in datos for s in i if s.startswith(nombre)]
        
    Mi_cursor.close()   

    Mi_conexion.close()



    Mi_conexion=sqlite3.connect("facturador/facturador2.db")

    Mi_cursor=Mi_conexion.cursor()  

    Mi_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM facturador2 WHERE NOMBRE_ARTICULO=?",nueva_lista)
    Mi_conexion.commit()

    datos2=Mi_cursor.fetchall()

    print(datos2)
        
    Mi_conexion.close()
```

Esto solo me sirve cuando el articulo encontrado es uno solo, pero como lo soluciono si son mas de uno( O sea yo no se que resultado voy a obtener al realizar la busqueda del numero de productos)

Comment: Hola, por favor revisa [ask]. Qué has intentado?

Comment: No se entendió estimado. Te aconsejo explicarlo de una manera totalmente distinta

Comment: el select si es mas de un articulo encontrado me da el error:Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Buscar "algo" que empiece con "otroalgo", se puede hacer en una sola consulta SQL usando LIKE

```
execute("SELECT * FROM facturador2 WHERE NOMBRE_ARTICULO LIKE '?%'",nombre)
```

Mas ejemplos de Like aquí: https://askavy.com/sql-starts-with-using-like/

Comment: Claro eso sí lo pude hacer,pero que pasa si es más de un producto encontrado? De esta forma cae el programa